# how to show data in a custom format in laravel resource api

Tags: laravel, api, resources

i have a controller that do some logic on some model and in the end i want to show it in a costum format that i show below :
so here is my controller end point where i send data to resource :

```
        return (new BookingStatusResource($hasdate))->additional($hasroom);
```

and in booking status resource i leave it as default like below :

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    return parent::toArray($request);
}
```

and finally this is the result i get :

```
{
   0: 1,
   1: 2,
   data: [
      "2019-03-31T19:30:00.000000Z",
      "2019-04-13T19:30:00.000000Z"
   ]
}
```

but i want to have it like below

```
{
   data: {
           {
              'hasdate':2019-03-31 19:30:00,
              'hasroom':3
           },
    ‌       {
               'hasdate':2019-02-21 12:20:00,
                'hasroom':2
           }
   }
}
```

Comment: Copy paste your model code

Answer (score 0):

use something like this:

```
$data=[];
foreach($dates as $date){
    $elem = [];
    $elem['hasdate']=$hasdate;
    $elem['hasroom'] = $hasroom;
}
$data=$elem;
```

Comment: the Result is yet the same like my old result first it shows all hasdates and then it shows all hasrooms

Comment: unfortunately no i think i must do some thing in my resource no ??‌kinda feel it like that